# Login from a site to another site in https

Tags: c#, asp.net, https

i'm new to stackoverflow and I have a question for you:

I have to do an automatic login from my wesite to another external website (not mine).

This site use https and when i go on the site address it ask me (with the classical popup form) to enter username and password.
I've tried to do a POST in this way

http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/05/05/send-a-https-post-request-with-c/

where in the string post_data I have put "Username=xxxx&Password=xxxx"

but doesn't work; the code returned was 401: Unauthorized.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to set up credentials? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx

Comment: Yes! I have now solved my problem! Thanks. Now I have another question: after doing the request and get the response, how can I redirect user in another page where he can view the page as logged user?